# How to bypass opengraph tags for Facebook like buttons and use data-href instead

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have the javascript code with the `fb-root` div installed right after my `<body>` tag.

There's a like button in the header of my website to like the website.

But there's more buttons on the website, for every article. Sometimes there's more than one on the same page.

So following facebook's docs instructions I added a `data-href=""` attribute to my `fb-like` tag. Didn't worked. Then I added a `ref=""` attribute with the article's slug inside it. Thought it would help.

The button with both data-href and ref attributes shows the same amount of likes as the website header's one. And when I click on them they both like the same url, not the url I specified in `data-href`. Any button ALWAYS uses data from the `opengraph` tags and completely ignores what I specify in the tag. (Which should be the opposite)

So the question is: Is there a way to bypass `OG` tags and force the URL from `data-href` to be used for a button? (It should work that way but I totally ignore why it doesn't).

Here's the code I use:

Right after :

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=MY_API_KEY>";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Then in the header:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="false" data-font="arial" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

And then in an article:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="URL_OF_THE_ARTICLE" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="175" data-show-faces="false" data-font="arial" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

I tried using both fb: and div tags by the way. This should be really simple, as it has been for Twitter and Google+.

Anyone has an idea of what's wrong with that?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure i understand the problem - the like button's data-href param should point to the URL of the content you want to like/share - that URL should contain the meta tags telling facebook what title, etc to display - you can see what facebook detects at that url with [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) - double-check you're not redirecting the crawler by changing the og:url tag, using a canonical meta tag, etc

Comment: You made me think that my OG tags are always the same and doesn't adapt to the page. I changed that behaviour and now it works. Thanks!!! If you want post this as an answer and I'll mark it as best answer!

Answer (score 0):

The like button's data-href param should point to the URL of the content you want to like/share -

That URL should contain the meta tags telling facebook what title, etc to display and return these tags to Facebook's crawler

You can see what facebook detects at that url with  [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) - double-check you're not redirecting the crawler by changing the `og:url` tag, using a canonical meta tag, etc