# Facebook like on more posts works as if I liked only 1 post

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, blogs

[Tristans.tk](http://tristans.tk)
This is my website.

This is the div that holds the like button:

```
<div class="like_holder">
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://tristans.tk/view/<?php echo $news_item['ID'] ?>" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="136" data-show-faces="false">
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the problem is if I click the like button, it likes all posts.
How can I make it that it likes individual ones? They clearly have different urls!.

Comment: I found the answer here: [Stackoverflow][1]



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865388/how-to-bypass-opengraph-tags-for-facebook-like-buttons-and-use-data-href-instead

Answer (score 0):

can you try making the og:url meta tag in you page dynamic and let us know if that fixes the problem?

thanks.

Comment: ah it seems you also reach the same conclusion :)